# Gradle deamon is not reused and jvmargs are not applied despite the values in project's gradle.properties file

Tags: java, gradle

Used gradle version: 3.4.1

I have specified `org.gradle.daemon=true` in my `gradle.properties`(located in my project root directory), though whenever I run my `gradlew` I see in the logs the following line:

> 22:50:26 Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
>
> 22:50:41 :broker:clean

As you can see the time difference between the execution of `clean` task and starting the gradle deamon , it takes around 15 seconds to start the deamon every time.

After the build is finished, when I run `./gradlew --status` command I see that there is no any running deamon as shown bellow:

> No Gradle daemons are running.
>
> PID    STATUS   INFO
>
> 10061 STOPPED  (by user or operating system)

Please answer the following questions:

1) So what is the reason that gradle deamon is not running in the background despite the instruction in gradle.properties (I don't have gradle.properties in gradle installation folder overriding the gradle.properties in project root) ?

2) Also, I see the same build time irrespective to the value I set to  `org.gradle.jvmargs` in `gradle.properties`, the build time is same for the values `-Xmx512M -Xms512M` and `-Xmx32M -Xms32M` and when I run `gradlew` with `--debug` option I always see the following line containing the value of `Xmx` equal to `1024m` irrespective to what value I have set for it in gradle.properties:

> 16:18:16.996 [INFO] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Starting process 'Gradle build daemon'. Working directory: /home/suren/.gradle/daemon/3.4.1 Command: /usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_202/bin/java -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError `-Xmx1024m` -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp /home/suren/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-3.4.1-bin/71zneekfcxxu7l9p7nr2sc65s/gradle-3.4.1/lib/gradle-launcher-3.4.1.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 3.4.1